# What causes Pyside6 to fail with Segmentation Fault

Tags: pyside6, python-3.11

I have a Pyside6 app with various GUI elements, where users select a script (Python or Shell) and run it using Python's subprocess.
Threading is used to deploy the script, while leaving the GUI interactive, e.g. display the script's output in a text box while it runs.

I can't share an example code, so I can only describe the issue I see:

Sometimes, after a couple of runs of a script, the GUI crashes with a "Segmentation Fault".

The exception stack seems to start with PySide6, but this happens only with a specific script.

What can I do to prevent the fault?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Pyside6 is failing, but the root cause lies in the threading running the Python\Shell scripts.

The way my app works is that it opens a thread to manage the run of the script using subprocess.popen(). The segmentation fault happens when the scripts run.

I increased the stack_size allocated for threading: `threading.stack_size(134217728)`

and it helped.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.stack_size(134217728)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The link is not valid, please fix it. Also, right now your question is extremely vague, and it's unclear the relation between the issue and the threading stack size, so you should try to improve the question (possibly explaining in detail what your program does, and eventually providing a valid [mre]) and this answer along with it. Besides, `subprocess.Popen()` runs another *process*, not another thread, there's *a lot* of difference.